# Is this games haram to play

Tags: halal-haram, game

Assalamunaleikum. I play two games :
-Ashpalt 9
-War Thunder Mobile.
Creator of Ashpalt 9 post their support to LGBT . War Thunder in on another hand , their PC version is cooperating with a adult star. Mobile version has no connection with this situtaion but both of are same company’s game. Does that make those games haram.